# Should mobile sitemaps point to canonical urls

Tags: sitemap, canonical-url, mobile, rel-canonical, rel-alternate

I've recently developed a mobile-friendly version of an old site.

The old site still does really well in the SERPs for key terms, so I don't want to redirect everyone (yet). But I do want to give mobile users a better experience, so I'm redirecting mobile users using the rel="alternate" mobile tag, as per [Google's recommendation](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls).

My question is, should the sitemap **on the mobile site** show the mobile urls or the canonical urls? Or should the sitemaps on both sites be the same, with appropriate annotations, e.g.:

```
<url>
<loc>http://www.example.com/page-1/</loc>
<xhtml:link
rel="alternate"
media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)"
href="http://m.example.com/page-1" />
</url>
```